# AWS: Can two private subnets in two AZs share the same NAT gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, availability-zone, aws-nat-gateway

I have one private subnet and one public subnet in one availability zone, and the same two subnets in another zone.

Can I create one NAT gateway in one public subnet, and create two route tables for the two private subnets, which both point to this single NAT gateway?

Or do I have to create two NAT gateways, one for each AZ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have one NAT gateway. But for high availability it's better to have one NAT gateway per AZ.

The docs clarify [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html):

> If you have resources in multiple Availability Zones and they share
>   one NAT gateway, in the event that the NAT gateway’s Availability Zone
>   is down, resources in the other Availability Zones lose internet
>   access.

Comment: Also you pay extra fee of data transfer between AZs